# Using Web API by Generating Entity Framework scaffolding API Controller Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have the fowling models:

```
public class Order 
{ 
    public int OrderId { get; set; } 
    //
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; } 
} 

public class Client 
{ 
    public int ClientId { get; set; } 
    public string ClientName { get; set; } 
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; } 
}
```

When I use Web Api by generating an EF scaffolding API controller, it didn't work. 
The error is below:

```
Self referencing loop detected for property 'Order' with type 
'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Order_A97AC61AD05BA6A886755C779FD3F96E86FE903ED7C9BA9400E79162C11BA719'. 
Path '[0].Order[0]'
```

Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Comment: The problem may be the serializer, you need to disable that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serializer can't handle circular references. You can disable it in the data context class:

```
public YourDbContext() : base("name=YourConnectionString") 
 { 
     Database.SetInitializer(new CircularReferenceDataInitializer()); 
     this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
     this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; 
 }
```

Like this, the navigation property won't be lazy loaded. If you want to use lazy loading, you can try the following:

1)  dealing with circular reference by ignoring it. Add the below code in your WebApiConfig.cs file.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

2)Preserve circular reference by adding the below code in your WebApiConfig.cs file.

```
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize; 
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

hope it helps.